# Force an Asynchronous call to behave Synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, microservices

In my React app, I'm trying to calculate a value based on three other values. I've contained all of the calculation logic to the back end, which is a microservice I make asynchronous calls to. The function in which I am asynchronously trying to get that calculated value is in the middle of many synchronous hooks.

In the UI layer, I call the function which I want to return the end result (returned asynchronously). That called function calls another function, which calls another function, which returns a new Promise. See code below:

```
// DateUI.js (layer 1)
selectDate(dateField, flight, idx, saved, momentTime, e) {
    if (moment(momentTime).isValid()) {
        if (dateField == "StartDate") {
            // The initial problematic function call, need to set endDate before I continue on
            let endDate = PlanLineActions.calculateFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, momentTimeUnix);

            flight.set("EndDate", endDate);
        }

        this.theNextSyncFunction(..., ..., ...);
    }
}


// DateActions.js (layer 2)
calculateFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate) {
    let plan = new Plan();

    plan.getFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate).then(function(response) {
        // response is JSON: {EndDate: "12/05/2016"}
        response.EndDate;
    }, function(error) {
        log.debug("There was an error calculating the End Date.");
    });
}


// DateClass.js (layer 3)
getFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate) {
    let path = '/path/to/microservice';
    return this.callServer(path, 'GET', {periodTypeId: periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods: numberOfPeriods, startDate: startDate});
}


// ServerLayer.js (layer 4)
callServer(path, method = "GET", query = {}, data, inject) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        super.callServer(uri.toString(),method,data,inject).then((data) => {
            resolve(data);
        }).catch((data) => {
            if (data.status === 401) {
                AppActions.doRefresh();
            }
            reject(data);
        });
    });
}
```

I am under the impression that, because ServerLayer.js (layer 4) returns a `new Promise` (and thus DateClass.js (layer 3)), calling `plan.getFlightEndDate(...).then(function(response) {...` will not complete until the response comes back resolved or rejected. This is not currently happening, as the code in DateUI.js (layer 1) will continue on to call `this.theNextSyncFunction`, and then resolve ~50ms later with the proper data.

How do I force PlanLineActions.calculateFlightEndDate(...) in DateUI.js (layer 1) to complete with a response before I continue on with selectDate()?

Comment: Those are some crazy function signatures.. I would consider using an object. Destructuring would be very useful for that.

Comment: @azium That would be the dream. Unfortunately the code provided above cuts out about 75% of the logic currently in place (the app is being reworked as we speak), and all of those separate signatures (assuming you're talking about function parameters) are currently necessary to be explicitly listed. If they were contained in an object, every hook in the chain would have to de- and re-structure that object, which may have performance issues (but definitely has readability issues).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by restructure.. you're doing React so maybe you've come across components that look like `let App = ({ someProps }) => <div>...` If you had performance issues from this I would be extremely surprised. Ajax calls are clearly your bottleneck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force something to be synchronous if it goes outside of the event loop like an ajax call. You're going to need something that looks like this:

```
PlanLineActions.calculateFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, momentTimeUnix)
  .then(endDate => {
    this.theNextSyncFunction(..., ..., ...);
  })
```

In order to do this, `calculateFlightEndDate` will also need to return a promise, and thus it's a good thing that promises are chainable.

```
calculateFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate) {
  let plan = new Plan();

  // return promise!
  return plan.getFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate).then(response => {
    return response.EndDate; // must return here
  }, error => {
    log.debug("There was an error calculating the End Date.");
  });
}
```

That should do it.. and one more thing: you're doubling up on promises in your server call. If something has `.then` it's already a promise, so you can just return that directly. no need to wrap in `new Promise` (a promise in a promise.. no need!)

```
callServer(path, method = "GET", query = {}, data, inject) {
  // just return!
  return super.callServer(uri.toString(),method,data,inject).then((data) => {
    return data;
  }).catch((data) => {
    if (data.status === 401) {
      AppActions.doRefresh();
    }
    throw data; // throw instead of reject
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, this solved it. I never thought to bring the rest of the `selectDate()` logic into a `then()` on success, I thought I had to force it to stop and complete (even though I knew this went against everything that async stands for) before it continued on with the function.

Comment: A question about the return statements though... when the function has `return ...() { return data`, this is very confusing. Is it stating that, when I call `calculateFlightEndDate`, it returns a promise which exists as its own entity that has a `return` statement inside of it?

Comment: both `new Promise` and the callback function you pass to `then` return promises. You need to return the promise initially to use it elsewhere.. and you need to return the value inside your callback function so that it appears as an argument inside `then`. This is why `.then` is chainable `ajax().then().then().then()`

Comment: @TylerBrown read this https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: How funny, I saw this article when it was released a year ago, yet didn't have the experience to consume it as I do now. Thank you for your comments in this question, you've been amazingly helpful @azium .

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand how promises work.

First of all, functions *always return immediately* so you won't ever block execution of the next lines of code (`flight.set` and `theNextSyncFunction()` in your case). This is the point of returning a promise: you get a promise *immediately* that you can attach a callback to (using `then()`) that will get invoked *later*. If you want code to wait for the promise to resolve you *have to put it in a `then()` callback.*

Secondly, your `calculateFlightEndDate()` is *not returning anything at all* so `endDate = calculateFlightEndDate()` is simply setting `endDate` to `undefined`.

### Solution

You should return a promise from `calculateFlightEndDate()` and put the code you want to execute afterwards inside a `then()` callback:

```
calculateFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate) {
    let plan = new Plan();

    return plan.getFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, startDate).then((response) => {
        // response is JSON: {EndDate: "12/05/2016"}
        return response.EndDate;
    }, (error) => {
        log.debug("There was an error calculating the End Date.");
    });
}

if (moment(momentTime).isValid()) {
    if (dateField == "StartDate") {
        PlanLineActions.calculateFlightEndDate(periodTypeId, numberOfPeriods, momentTimeUnix).then((endDate) => {
            flight.set("EndDate", endDate);
            this.theNextSyncFunction(...);
        });
    }
}
```

You could also look into using [ES7 `async` and `await`](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) which allows you to *write* your async code so that it *looks* synchronous, but uses promises under the hood to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. You were right about my misunderstanding of promises. I expected a `.then()` to wait and complete before continuing on with the entire chain, but it just waits to complete what is *inside* of the `.then(func(success) {...` area.

Comment: I think you should drop the doubling up of promises!

Comment: That's fair, the wrapping promise isn't doing anything here. Edited it out.